# generate random alphanumeric key in Ms. Access

Tags: mysql, database, excel, ms-access, vbscript

by having this code on VB Script

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ltr, rNum, AlphaLtrs, selLtr

If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(2)) Is Nothing And _
   Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    If Target.Value = "" Then

        AlphaLtrs = "ABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        selLtr = Application.RoundUp(Rnd() * 26, 0)
        ltr = Mid(AlphaLtrs, selLtr, 1)
        rNum = Application.RoundUp(Rnd() * 999999, 0)
        Target.Value = Me.Range("A" & Target.Row) & "-" & ltr & rNum
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

I need to create it through Ms. Access, Generally for Stock Keeping Products

Ms Access Table Contains this Fields

```
ID [Primary Key]
Product Title [Short text]
Type [Short text]
SKU [Short text]
Image Preview [Attachment]
Price [Number]
Availability [yes/No]
```

what i need is SKU will be auto Generate Keys for any new Product, Unique Key, may be by a button on form while inserting a new entry or may be by initially new entry , Key will be same as the Excel Code e.g. Z401374 (alpha numeric) and once Generated cant be change

Answer (score 1):

Drop this into a module and run it.  You should get what you need.

```
Sub test()

    Dim s As String * 7 'fixed length string with 7 characters
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim ch As Integer 'the character
    For n = 1 To Len(s) 'don't hardcode the length twice
        Do
            ch = Rnd() * 127 'This could be more efficient.
            '48 is '0', 57 is '9', 65 is 'A', 90 is 'Z', 97 is 'a', 122 is 'z'.
        Loop While ch < 48 Or ch > 57 And ch < 65 Or ch > 90 And ch < 97 Or ch > 122
        Mid(s, n, 1) = Chr(ch) 'bit more efficient than concatenation
    Next

    Debug.Print s

End Sub
```

What you'll probably then have to do is do an INNER JOIN on your table (or SELECT SKU from tblProducts WHERE SKU = "the above generated string") to make sure it didn't randomly generate the same string twice.  Eventually, with enough SKUs, that will happen.  If it did, just re-run the generator and test again until you don't find a match, and then you know you have a unique SKU.

Comment: i need some handy solution , please

Comment: I just gave you one.  Use it.